# How to convert remove "\n" & "\" from the string & convert that string to JSON or dict

Tags: python, json

I want to convert this data into json or python dictionary.

What would be the best possible way of doing it as I have at least 3GB of data like this.

```
"{\"domain\":\"defb2b00f609c6bb8fcfd43af70c146bc8a26036f800e8f7563bc366fb88aa1f\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9,66],\"confidence\":0.90371,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"e7378a78724fcd254b59764f451be766d0e1c6683eac9aa3d5f29798600d91af\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9,59],\"confidence\":0.90371,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"5f616b8a7b283395961018da6ac75a563efdfcf743ce7e1cd1bcbec0a23a5349\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[18],\"confidence\":0.70767,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"4e219482bd58e2c7d91c55e52aa5db37785f29314e4db9c319ab9edb9ee5de1e\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9],\"confidence\":0.8198000000000001,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"e3ad60e6f8786da0253d8ce00fcb90ee5bf497a75c5b42753acba203800ad6fe\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9],\"confidence\":0.8198000000000001,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"49ae5ad8cc8de0136f3f99a1330710a14912fb743578d4ce39318281979162b4\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[26],\"confidence\":0.9594,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"f93af67b58299d7317841de70464624ffc0190b93a4af860dcc58038162a30cf\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9,62],\"confidence\":0.70767,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"c9356044593f00f2b779cbd59246695e654bf1f105a265867d4f06c1bb6a2ea2\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[66,68],\"confidence\":0.70767,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"7920da2f3dc7de646d3434d467ffccdd8ca31115c54529bc2a4d758896ae1a19\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[4,74],\"confidence\":0.8198000000000001,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"08a4027677824509beee405482a5f1a5f4feddbf0aafbf4b649c2909732f6909\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[75],\"confidence\":0.8198000000000001,\"tier\":2}\n"
```

Comment: It already is  a JSON string. If you want a dict, what happens when you use `json.loads(string)`?

Comment: when I check the type it still returns < class str>

Comment: As far as I can tell, what you've shown is not a valid JSON string. It is multiple objects separated by `\n`... Have you tried splitting those?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you fix what is generating the data. Otherwise, split the newlines

```
>>> s = "... your string ..."
>>> data = [json.loads(x) for x in s.splitlines()]
>>> for x in data:
...   print(x['tier'])
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
```

https://jsonlines.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it to a `bytes` type string, then decode it using `unicode_escape` to remove the escapes. It's the opposite of [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
unescaped = bytes(s, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
```

Then just read it as any other JSONL *([jsonlines](https://jsonlines.org/))* object

```
list(map(json.loads, unescaped.split('\n')))
```

Output:

```
[
    {'domain': 'defb2b00f609c6bb8fcfd43af70c146bc8a26036f800e8f7563bc366fb88aa1f', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9, 66], 'confidence': 0.90371, 'tier': 2},
    {'domain': 'e7378a78724fcd254b59764f451be766d0e1c6683eac9aa3d5f29798600d91af', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9, 59], 'confidence': 0.90371, 'tier': 2},
    {'domain': '5f616b8a7b283395961018da6ac75a563efdfcf743ce7e1cd1bcbec0a23a5349', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [18], 'confidence': 0.70767, 'tier': 2},
    {'domain': '4e219482bd58e2c7d91c55e52aa5db37785f29314e4db9c319ab9edb9ee5de1e', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9], 'confidence': 0.8198000000000001, 'tier': 2},
    {'domain': 'e3ad60e6f8786da0253d8ce00fcb90ee5bf497a75c5b42753acba203800ad6fe', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9], 'confidence': 0.8198000000000001, 'tier': 2},
    {'domain': '49ae5ad8cc8de0136f3f99a1330710a14912fb743578d4ce39318281979162b4', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [26], 'confidence': 0.9594, 'tier': 2},
    {'domain': 'f93af67b58299d7317841de70464624ffc0190b93a4af860dcc58038162a30cf', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9, 62], 'confidence': 0.70767, 'tier': 2},
    {'domain': 'c9356044593f00f2b779cbd59246695e654bf1f105a265867d4f06c1bb6a2ea2', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [66, 68], 'confidence': 0.70767, 'tier': 2},
    {'domain': '7920da2f3dc7de646d3434d467ffccdd8ca31115c54529bc2a4d758896ae1a19', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [4, 74], 'confidence': 0.8198000000000001, 'tier': 2},
    {'domain': '08a4027677824509beee405482a5f1a5f4feddbf0aafbf4b649c2909732f6909', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [75], 'confidence': 0.8198000000000001, 'tier': 2}
]
```

Comment: I tried it  ```unescaped = bytes(res, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
a = set(map(json.loads, unescaped.split('\n')))
print(a)``` but returns `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex for this:

```
import re
import json

regex = r"\\(\")|\\n"

test_str = ("\"{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"defb2b00f609c6bb8fcfd43af70c146bc8a26036f800e8f7563bc366fb88aa1f\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[9,66],\\\"confidence\\\":0.90371,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"e7378a78724fcd254b59764f451be766d0e1c6683eac9aa3d5f29798600d91af\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[9,59],\\\"confidence\\\":0.90371,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"5f616b8a7b283395961018da6ac75a563efdfcf743ce7e1cd1bcbec0a23a5349\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[18],\\\"confidence\\\":0.70767,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"4e219482bd58e2c7d91c55e52aa5db37785f29314e4db9c319ab9edb9ee5de1e\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[9],\\\"confidence\\\":0.8198000000000001,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"e3ad60e6f8786da0253d8ce00fcb90ee5bf497a75c5b42753acba203800ad6fe\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[9],\\\"confidence\\\":0.8198000000000001,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"49ae5ad8cc8de0136f3f99a1330710a14912fb743578d4ce39318281979162b4\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[26],\\\"confidence\\\":0.9594,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"f93af67b58299d7317841de70464624ffc0190b93a4af860dcc58038162a30cf\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[9,62],\\\"confidence\\\":0.70767,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"c9356044593f00f2b779cbd59246695e654bf1f105a265867d4f06c1bb6a2ea2\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[66,68],\\\"confidence\\\":0.70767,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"7920da2f3dc7de646d3434d467ffccdd8ca31115c54529bc2a4d758896ae1a19\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[4,74],\\\"confidence\\\":0.8198000000000001,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n{\\\"domain\\\":\\\"08a4027677824509beee405482a5f1a5f4feddbf0aafbf4b649c2909732f6909\\\",\\\"path\\\":\\\"/\\\",\\\"scope\\\":\\\"domain\\\",\\\"categories\\\":[75],\\\"confidence\\\":0.8198000000000001,\\\"tier\\\":2}\\n\"\n")

subst = "\\g<1>"

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
if result.startswith('"') and result.endswith('"'):
    result = result[1:-1]
if result:
    print (result)
    object_result = json.loads(result)
    print(object_result)
```

Comment: result is still the string. How can I convert it to json or dict?

Comment: you can use json package and it's loads function do what you want. I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of `ast.literal_eval()` to safely evaluate list of objects within string literal.

```py
>>> raw_string = "{\"domain\":\"defb2b00f609c6bb8fcfd43af70c146bc8a26036f800e8f7563bc366fb88aa1f\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9,66],\"confidence\":0.90371,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"e7378a78724fcd254b59764f451be766d0e1c6683eac9aa3d5f29798600d91af\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9,59],\"confidence\":0.90371,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"5f616b8a7b283395961018da6ac75a563efdfcf743ce7e1cd1bcbec0a23a5349\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[18],\"confidence\":0.70767,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"4e219482bd58e2c7d91c55e52aa5db37785f29314e4db9c319ab9edb9ee5de1e\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9],\"confidence\":0.8198000000000001,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"e3ad60e6f8786da0253d8ce00fcb90ee5bf497a75c5b42753acba203800ad6fe\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9],\"confidence\":0.8198000000000001,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"49ae5ad8cc8de0136f3f99a1330710a14912fb743578d4ce39318281979162b4\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[26],\"confidence\":0.9594,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"f93af67b58299d7317841de70464624ffc0190b93a4af860dcc58038162a30cf\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[9,62],\"confidence\":0.70767,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"c9356044593f00f2b779cbd59246695e654bf1f105a265867d4f06c1bb6a2ea2\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[66,68],\"confidence\":0.70767,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"7920da2f3dc7de646d3434d467ffccdd8ca31115c54529bc2a4d758896ae1a19\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[4,74],\"confidence\":0.8198000000000001,\"tier\":2}\n{\"domain\":\"08a4027677824509beee405482a5f1a5f4feddbf0aafbf4b649c2909732f6909\",\"path\":\"/\",\"scope\":\"domain\",\"categories\":[75],\"confidence\":0.8198000000000001,\"tier\":2}\n"

>>> modified_string = raw_string.replace('\\','').replace('\n',',')

>>> import ast
>>> dicts = ast.literal_eval(modified_string)      # a tuple of dictionaries

>>> for d in dicts:
...     print(d)
... 
{'domain': 'defb2b00f609c6bb8fcfd43af70c146bc8a26036f800e8f7563bc366fb88aa1f', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9, 66], 'confidence': 0.90371, 'tier': 2}
{'domain': 'e7378a78724fcd254b59764f451be766d0e1c6683eac9aa3d5f29798600d91af', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9, 59], 'confidence': 0.90371, 'tier': 2}
{'domain': '5f616b8a7b283395961018da6ac75a563efdfcf743ce7e1cd1bcbec0a23a5349', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [18], 'confidence': 0.70767, 'tier': 2}
{'domain': '4e219482bd58e2c7d91c55e52aa5db37785f29314e4db9c319ab9edb9ee5de1e', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9], 'confidence': 0.8198000000000001, 'tier': 2}
{'domain': 'e3ad60e6f8786da0253d8ce00fcb90ee5bf497a75c5b42753acba203800ad6fe', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9], 'confidence': 0.8198000000000001, 'tier': 2}
{'domain': '49ae5ad8cc8de0136f3f99a1330710a14912fb743578d4ce39318281979162b4', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [26], 'confidence': 0.9594, 'tier': 2}
{'domain': 'f93af67b58299d7317841de70464624ffc0190b93a4af860dcc58038162a30cf', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [9, 62], 'confidence': 0.70767, 'tier': 2}
{'domain': 'c9356044593f00f2b779cbd59246695e654bf1f105a265867d4f06c1bb6a2ea2', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [66, 68], 'confidence': 0.70767, 'tier': 2}
{'domain': '7920da2f3dc7de646d3434d467ffccdd8ca31115c54529bc2a4d758896ae1a19', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [4, 74], 'confidence': 0.8198000000000001, 'tier': 2}
{'domain': '08a4027677824509beee405482a5f1a5f4feddbf0aafbf4b649c2909732f6909', 'path': '/', 'scope': 'domain', 'categories': [75], 'confidence': 0.8198000000000001, 'tier': 2}
```